# Conference microphone that can be daisy chained?

Tags: microphones

I'm looking for a conference microphone, similar to something out of the Jabra Speak series. My requirements are:

- Must be combined speaker and microhpone.
- Must have omnidirectional microphone intended to pick up audio from multiple persons.
- Must have both Bluetooth and USB connection.
- Must be possible to daisy chain, i.e. connect two of them at different ends of a table in order to pick up audio from larger groups. (Daisy chaining more than two is a bonus, but not a requirement.)
- A price of 300$ is acceptable, anything below 200$ is good.

The [Jabra Speak 710](https://www.jabra.com/business/speakerphones/jabra-speak-series/jabra-speak-710##7710-309) would be an example that fits the bill but has a hefty price at 314$. The [Jabra Speak 510](https://www.jabra.com/business/speakerphones/jabra-speak-series/jabra-speak-710##7710-309) would be an example that does not work, since it can't be daisy chained.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively generic conference speaker that should fit all of your requirements for €199: the [EMEET Bluetooth Conference Speaker](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B09X5D1JGL).

Comment: You could improve your answer by recommending a few(with details/specs)

Comment: Hi Steven, echoing what Rohit said; if you could provide some additional info clarifying the reasoning behind your selection, that'd be great.